# Error including dlib library in c++ project

Tags: c++, makefile, dlib

I need to include dlib in a c++ project. I have properly linked the library in my Makefile. Here is the Makefile:

```
EXE = face_frontalization
OBJ_DIR = bin

CFLAGS = -g -w
# CXXFLAGS = -w -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++0x
# LDFLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_gfx -lm

dummy_build_folder := $(shell mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR))

 # c++ source files of the project
CXXFILES = $(shell find src -type f -name '*.cpp')
CXXOBJ = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,bin/%.o,$(CXXFILES))

INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/dlib-18.18
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`
CXXFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -w -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS = -lcurl
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -g -w

MKDIR = mkdir -p

ifdef V
MUTE =
VTAG = -v
else
MUTE = @
endif

###################################################################
# This is a Makefile progress indicator.
# BUILD is initially undefined

ifndef BUILD

# max equals 256 x's
sixteen := x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
MAX := $(foreach x,$(sixteen),$(sixteen))

# T estimates how many targets we are building by replacing BUILD with
# a special string
T := $(shell $(MAKE) -nrRf $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $(MAKECMDGOALS) \
            BUILD="COUNTTHIS" | grep -c "COUNTTHIS")

# N is the number of pending targets in base 1, well in fact, base x
# :-)
N := $(wordlist 1,$T,$(MAX))

# auto-decrementing counter that returns the number of pending targets
# in base 10
counter = $(words $N)$(eval N := $(wordlist 2,$(words $N),$N))

# BUILD is now defined to show the progress, this also avoids
# redefining T in loop
BUILD = @echo $(counter) of $(T)
endif
###################################################################

# .PHONY: directories all
#
# directories: ${OUT_DIR}
# ${OUT_DIR}:
#   ${MKDIR} ${OUT_DIR}


all: $(EXE)
    # build successful


$(EXE): $(CXXOBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXOBJ) -o $(EXE) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@
    $(BUILD)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@

run: all
    ./$(EXE)

clean:
    # Cleaning...
    -rm -f $(EXE) $(CXXOBJ)
    rmdir bin/
```

I dont know why but its giving errors on compilation. I have compiled the dlib library itself too and the code examples are running as they should.
The error I am getting is:

```
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `fatial_feature_detector()':
/home/playroom/Desktop/face-frontalization/src/fatialfeaturedetect.cpp:20: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::wait_until_closed() const'
/home/playroom/Desktop/face-frontalization/src/fatialfeaturedetect.cpp:18: undefined reference to `dlib::image_window::~image_window()'
/home/playroom/Desktop/face-frontalization/src/fatialfeaturedetect.cpp:18: undefined reference to `dlib::image_window::~image_window()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::get_serialized_frontal_faces()':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h:115: undefined reference to `dlib::base64::base64()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h:2358: undefined reference to `dlib::base64::decode(std::istream&, std::ostream&) const'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h:2367: undefined reference to `dlib::base64::~base64()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h:2367: undefined reference to `dlib::base64::~base64()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib_check_consistent_assert_usage':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/../gui_core/../threads/threads_kernel_shared.h:44: undefined reference to `USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::drawable_window::drawable_window(bool, bool)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h:79: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::base_window(bool, bool)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h:79: undefined reference to `vtable for dlib::drawable_window'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h:79: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::~base_window()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::drawable_window::~drawable_window()':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h:195: undefined reference to `vtable for dlib::drawable_window'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h:195: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::close_window()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/drawable.h:195: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::~base_window()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::scrollable_region_style_default::draw_scrollable_region_border(dlib::canvas const&, dlib::rectangle const&, bool) const':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/style.h:527: undefined reference to `dlib::draw_sunken_rectangle(dlib::canvas const&, dlib::rectangle const&, unsigned char)'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::image_display::disable_overlay_editing()':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3485: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&)'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::compress_stream_kernel_1<dlib::entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5<257ul, dlib::entropy_encoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>, dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5<257ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>, dlib::crc32>::decompress(std::istream&, std::ostream&) const':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../compress_stream/compress_stream_kernel_1.h:180: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../compress_stream/compress_stream_kernel_1.h:181: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::set_stream(std::istream&)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../compress_stream/compress_stream_kernel_1.h:196: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../compress_stream/compress_stream_kernel_1.h:201: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../compress_stream/compress_stream_kernel_1.h:243: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../compress_stream/compress_stream_kernel_1.h:243: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `void dlib::image_window::add_overlay<dlib::rgb_pixel>(std::vector<dlib::rectangle, std::allocator<dlib::rectangle> > const&, dlib::rgb_pixel)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3968: undefined reference to `dlib::image_window::add_overlay(std::vector<dlib::image_display::overlay_rect, std::allocator<dlib::image_display::overlay_rect> > const&)'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::image_window::image_window<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3883: undefined reference to `vtable for dlib::image_window'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3883: undefined reference to `dlib::image_display::image_display(dlib::drawable_window&)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3885: undefined reference to `dlib::image_window::on_image_clicked(dlib::vector<long, 2l> const&, bool, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3888: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::show()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3883: undefined reference to `dlib::image_display::~image_display()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5<257ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:422: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:456: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:503: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:551: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:553: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `void dlib::image_window::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3930: undefined reference to `dlib::image_display::get_image_display_rect() const'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3934: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::set_size(int, int)'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `void dlib::load_dng<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::istream&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:585: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:586: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::set_stream(std::istream&)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:757: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:771: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:772: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::set_stream(std::istream&)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:771: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:757: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_loader/image_loader.h:771: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `void dlib::image_display::set_image<dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3272: undefined reference to `dlib::scrollable_region::set_total_rect_size(unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3274: undefined reference to `dlib::scrollable_region::set_total_rect_size(unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3278: undefined reference to `dlib::base_window::invalidate_rectangle(dlib::rectangle const&)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/widgets.h:3283: undefined reference to `dlib::popup_menu_region::disable()'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5<256ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:422: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:456: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:503: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:551: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5.h:553: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
bin/fatialfeaturedetect.o: In function `dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4<256ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4.h:348: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4.h:376: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4.h:422: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4.h:469: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
/usr/include/dlib-18.18/dlib/image_processing/../entropy_decoder_model/entropy_decoder_model_kernel_4.h:471: undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [face_frontalization] Error 1
```

I cant figure out what I have done in linking the library to the project. Please help.

Comment: Where are the linkage commands?

Comment: Please run `ldd -r ` on your dlib library and exe and make sure no undefined symbols reported

Comment: Let's say you exe is called `<some path>/my_exe`. You need to run `ldd -r <some path>/my_exe` and see that no errors are reported. If you see errors, you have to add missing libraries to the link line and/or missing path(s) to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or its analog.

Comment: I dont have an executable because there is an error in the code. So I cant really do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Do that with your `dlib` library as I seems that the problem is with linking of that library?

Comment: Dlib doesn't produce exe files. Its made up of  just headers. It does have examples which are .cpp which I have run and they all work.

Comment: You have said that dlib produced a library. I propose you to check that library. `ldd` analyzes both exe and shared libraries. You have a linkage/loading problem. It means that you have to verify that all the required libraries exist in the linking list and all those libraries can be found by the loader (this is where LD_LIBRARY_PATH comes in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dlib is partially header-based and some functions need to have libdlib.a linked to a project
You have two ways how to solve your problem:

1. link to dlib: LDFLAGS = -ldlib (dlib should be installed or its path provided to linker)
2. add dlib/all/source.cpp to your project sources list(CXXFILES)

Comment: On doing the 1st thing, it doesn't recognize -ldlib. On 2nd pt., the error is:   src/source.cpp:7:41: fatal error: ../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp: No such file or directory
 #include "../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp"

Comment: you should not copy source.cpp into your project but instead give full absolute path to it

Comment: Now the error is:   /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccps6CPH.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [face_frontalization] Error 1

Comment: And how do I install Dlib? I have only found how to compile it using cmake.

Comment: cmake --build . --target install

Comment: how about compiling whole your project with cmake?

Comment: It'd be better if I was able to work everything out using makefile. How can I resolve the error?

Comment: I havent been able to remove this error: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUl3XLr.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line.     
As much as I read, it is caused by wrong order of linking. I have tried changing the order and checking pkg-config outputs but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If this error is present during compilation with dLib:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccps6CPH.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' 
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [face_frontalization] Error 1
```

There is a good probability that X11 is missing. I dont know what it is so if somebody does, please tell me. Solution is to just add `-lX11` to the `LDFLAGS` in order to link with it. If you dont want it, you can also specify compiler option `-DDLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT`.

(NOTE: I haven't tested it and dont know what X11 does so better include it than exclude it.)